# Search two tables in one query

Tags: sql-server, select

Is there any way to search two tables in one query?

I have two tables:

```
sarcshiftcentertable
id
startdate
enddate

sarcshiftpointtable
id 
startdate
enddate
point_id
```

I want to search these two tables, like combining them but not horizontally,
vertically.

I want to select the startdate and the enddate from these two tables in one query. 
Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is a little hard to understand, but it sounds like you might want to look into the `UNION` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :

```
SELECT id, startdate, enddate , '-' AS point_id 
FROM sarcshiftcentertable 
WHERE startdate >='2014-05-27'
AND enddate <='2014-06-27'
UNION
SELECT id, startdate, enddate, point_id 
FROM sarcshiftpointtable 
WHERE startdate >='2014-05-27'
AND enddate <='2014-06-27'
```